# Accessing a datatemplate control in WPF programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

In my WPF application I have a list of `DocumentViewers` which are bound to some property of an object. I add the object to a ListBox and programmatically apply a datatemplate which binds the property of the object to the DocumentViewer. This means the DocumentViewer isn't declared at all in the code, but I want to get at it to change a property later on. How can I do this? My code looks like the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeDataTemplate" x:Name="DocumentViewerTempl">
    <DocumentViewer x:Name="DocV" Document="{Binding DocumentContent}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DocumentViewerStyle1}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The contents of the document are in the `DocumentContent` property of the `Document` class, so as you can see, the binding takes place above. My question is how to access the DocumentViewer in the code? I've tried giving it a name and referencing that but that's clearly not the way to do it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx):

```
var itemContainer = 
    listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;

// or: 
var itemContainer = 
    listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;

var viewer = 
    itemContainer.ContentTemplate.FindName("DocV", itemContainer) as DocumentViewer;

// Do stuff with viewer
```